# how to fix the path for my request to a go server from a polymer app?

Tags: http, go, localhost, polymer-3.x

I am working on a GO/Polymer app (Polymer as frontEnd and go as Backend) the server is done with go and functioning and the app with polymer and it is working aswell.

The problem i have is when i try to run the app on localhost my requests are sent to the wrong socket so the server never gets them therefore i cannot test anything nor modify the existing app.

I'm trying to run the app that has already been built by others and add new features but i am a beginner with polymer.
I tried to modify the URL given in the requests... without any success...

the server :

```golang
router.PathPrefix("/polymer/").Handler(http.StripPrefix("/polymer/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("/polymer/build/es6-bundled/"))))
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", router))
```

The directories are set up this way : 
C://Users/go/Myapp/

in this you will find a server directory with all .go files
and a polymer directory with the files related to polymer and the frontend.

So when i run the server and build/serve the polymer app i get the following link : http://127.0.0.1:8081
when i try to use a query (e.g connecting to the app with credentials stored in a mongoDB database.) it sends the following link  http://127.0.0.1/8081/login/?password=xxxx&username=xxxxx

So it never reaches the server which is listening to the socket 8080. 
When i change the request link to http://127.0.0.1:8080/login/?password=xxxx&username=xxxxx i get the response from the server.

So i know where the problem is but i dont know how to fix it to run my app on the localhost...

Thank you for helping ! If you need anymore resources i can provide.

Comment: Can't you just change your go port from `8080` to `8081`?

Comment: you mean in the ListenAndServe method? the problem is it also runs on the 8080 socket. So i cannot just change the port to 8081 otherwise i wont be able the run the polymer app

Comment: Why are you serving the Polymer app? Shouldn't you just build it and make Go serve it? If you're running the Polymer app with something like `npm` or `yarn`, the frontend will not be able to find the Go server without extra work.

Comment: Thank you ! 
That was in fact the problem. I was running go and polymer both at the same time.
Plus in the version given to me the directories were not at the right position so that's why i had some 404 errors when running only go. Moving the polymer files in the right dir made everything work !
problem fixed ! Thanks everyone